# How to add a like page button on each post?

Tags: facebook, post, facebook-like, facebook-page

I saw a lot of pages these days having a "Like Page" Button on the right of the page name. I know sponsored pages have that facility but i recently saw some pages's post on which the post wasn't sponsored yet the post had one such button.

Here's a Grabbed image to explain exactly what i am talking about : [Here](http://tinypic.com/r/xm8k1c/6)

Any Idea how this is achieved? 
How can i get the same thing for my Facebook page?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Facebook decides this based on its own algorithms ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This option appears when a friend of yours likes/shares/comments on a post. The part `...barpande likes a photo` is because he has liked the photo. It then embeds the image/liked content, along with an invite to like the page.